# Special characters in django allauth subject line

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-allauth, django-email

I am using allauth's ResetPasswordForm for password reset process. This form's save method sends the password reset email. I customized the password reset template to use it in Turkish, so it includes some special characters. The email message itself is printed perfectly, displaying the special characters the right way. However, the subject line is printed as below for a subject I enter e.g. "öla".

"Subject: =?utf-8?b?W2V4YW1wbGUuY29tXSDDtmxh?="

If I give the subject "ola" without using the accent, there is no problem, it prints

"Subject: ola"

to the console. To stress again, this does not happen in the email body, which prints several special characters correctly. I only changed the allauth's template, and did not change anything in the form class.

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: did you try to look to subject field in actual email browser as this is exactly a format RFC 1342 defines

Comment: no, i didn't know this could be an issue. i sent a real email using the smtp backend, and the subject line now shows up nicely on a browser and on mobile. thanks so much. resolved.